# Execute task on shutdown executor service - no exception?

Tags: java, executorservice

any ideas why default java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor doesnt throw any exception if I try to execute task on executor service which is shutdown? ( executorService.shutdown() was called before )

Yes, my rejection handler is invoked but still task is not run because:

```
if (!e.isShutdown()) {
            r.run();
        }
```

I wonder if not throwing any exception is behaviour by design or a glitch...

Its just misleading when it silently fails.

//forgot to mention - its java 6 in this case

Comment: Can you show more code? Also, why execute the task yourself if you use an executor?

Comment: i use it, I just call:
executorService.execute(new ExecutorHandler(sb.toString()));

Comment: Running this code: `final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); pool.shutdown();
 pool.execute(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {} });` throws a `RejectedExecutionException`. Your question lacks sufficent information to reproduce your problem.